# How can I know when a player quits out of a turn from the Game Center UI?

Tags: ios, game-center

In an iOS Game Center managed turn based game, if a player quits out of turn from the Game Center UI, then `turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:playerQuitForMatch` isn't called (as expected). However, the other players don't seem to receive any `handleTurnEventForMatch:` notifications either. Is this correct?

If this is the expected behaviour, how is the game to become aware that someone has quit in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, it seems to have been one of the regular sandbox notification outages.

I tried exactly the same code and devices again today, and this time the second device received a `handleTurnEventForMatch:` with the quitting player's `matchOutcome` equal tot `Quit`.

Comment: Make sure to mark this as accepted if this solved your problem.